# Open two IE windows with multiple links with timeout (BATCH)

Tags: javascript, batch-file, vbscript, cmd

For example, I want it to open 4 tabs of google.com on **1ST** IE WINDOW,
each tab I set a 1 second timeout to load for the next tab

***AFTER,***  2 seconds... I want it to open another 4 tabs of google.com on a new **2ND** IE WINDOW, each tab still set with a 1 second timeout for the next tab.

So far I came up with:

```
    @echo off
    start "1" "www.google.com"
    ping 1.1.1.1 -n 1 -w 1000 > nul
    start "2" "www.google.com"
    ping 1.1.1.1 -n 1 -w 1000 > nul
    start "3" "www.google.com"
    ping 1.1.1.1 -n 1 -w 1000 > nul
    exit
```

The code is good for the 1st IE window, the problem is how to command the same for the 2nd window using a single batch?

I've attached an image of what I want to achieve below:

[image]

Comment: ...this might be kind of academic but: to implement a delay of one second, I'd use `ping 127.0.0.1 -n 2 > nul`, because `127.0.0.1` will always exist (`-n 2` to do two `ping` attempts with a pause of 1 s in between); `1.1.1.1` might exist, so `-w 1000` had not effect and therefore no delay occurs...

Answer (score 0):

Start another instance of IE and see it the new windows will be added to it.

```
@echo off
start "1" "www.google.com"
ping 1.1.1.1 -n 1 -w 1000 > nul
start "2" "www.google.com"
ping 1.1.1.1 -n 1 -w 1000 > nul
start "3" "www.google.com"
ping 1.1.1.1 -n 1 -w 1000 > nul

"%ProgramFiles%\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe"

start "4" "www.google.com"
ping 1.1.1.1 -n 1 -w 1000 > nul
start "5" "www.google.com"
ping 1.1.1.1 -n 1 -w 1000 > nul
start "6" "www.google.com"
ping 1.1.1.1 -n 1 -w 1000 > nul
exit
```

Comment: there's something wrong, yes it opens a new IE, but when its opening each tab its stop from 1 or 2 then goes back in the 1st window it will continue to open tabs there...its like on the 1st window 3tabs, then 2nd window 2tabs goes back to 1st window for the last tab... 4/2 instead 3/3